# Expression for "abundant source of"

Tags: vocabulary, figurative-language

What figurative expression could I use to describe "an abundant source of"? 
The context is the following:

*the Amazon is a true Free University of Sciences and Philosophy, and authentic ___________ of arts and crafts.*

I've found "gold mine", but I believe it wouldn't fit here. Other expressions I considered using were: "cellar" and "granary", but I don't know how they sound for a native. Do they sound very far-fetched?

I don't want the sentence to sound too informal, so I guess I should avoid things like *golden goose, cash cow, bonanza, El Dorado*.

Comment: [**cornucopia** synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cornucopia)

Comment: @FumbleFingers yeah that's the one I was trying to remember.

Comment: You've limited the choice somewhat with the word **authentic**.  BTW, you need an article, "and **an** authentic .... of arts and crafts"

Comment: I would probably use "a veritable ____" or "a bona fide ____" instead of "an authentic ____"

Comment: Although not the sense you're looking for, but I think a good fit in your context might be *sanctuary*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want the word "wellspring":

> noun
>
> 1.
>   the head or source of a spring, stream, river, etc.; fountainhead.
>
> **2.
>   a source or supply of anything, especially when considered inexhaustible:
>   a wellspring of affection.**

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wellspring

Answer (score 4):

Maybe words like **"depository"** or **"storehouse"** will do? A common informal noun is **"well"**

Comment: Yes -- well, or spring, or springhead.  There's also another word that goes with "well" that's on the tip of my tongue.

Comment: @Andrew Goldmine? Treasure house? Klondaik?

Comment: I think it was "wellspring".  But anyway OP says he doesn't like "gold mine", and "treasure house" is somewhat synonymous with that.  Both fit, in my opinion.

Comment: I guess **wellspring** and **well** are synonyns.

Comment: Wellspring implies it's the *source* of the water but it's not as commonly used.  "Fountainhead" is another similar watery metaphor.

Comment: "Fount" is another word for, I think, wellspring. "Font" is a related word that is sometimes used in the same context. E.g. "font of wisdom" or "fount of wisdom."

Answer (score 4):

"Fount" is possible, as in "he was a fount of wisdom".

"Cellar" and "granary" are not idiomatic, but "storehouse" is, with probably the same metaphorical usage.

Also ["cornucopia"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cornucopia) (as FumbleFingers mentions in his comment).